# Should array_push() be used for building an array through an iterative approach in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

If I wanted to build an array with pairs of data that follow a pattern like `$n => myFunction($n)`, I think I want to do something like this:

```
$myArray = array();

foreach ($n as $key) {
    $new_data = array($key => myFunction($key));
    array_push($myArray, $new_data);
}
```

However, I’ve heard developers criticize the array_push() function, so I wonder if there is a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not bad per se, but function calls in PHP are relatively slow, so if you avoid `array_push` throughout your code, you may notice the effect. Personally I always use the `[]` notation, mainly because I think it's cleaner, but it's also faster.

```
$myArray[] = $new_data;
```

Even the [documentation of `array_push`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) mentions this alternative as a faster one:

> Note: If you use `array_push()` to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = 
>   because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.

But there's also the advantage of `array_push`, you can use it to push multiple elements to an array:

```
array_push($myArray, 'value1', 'value2', 'value3');
```

So it has its uses, but for adding single elements at a time, like you do, the shorter notation of `$myArray[] = ...` is faster.

Comment: Mentioning performance where it is absurdly unlikely to matter. Avoiding function calls for performance reasons is a horrible advice, regardless of what you might think of `array_push`

Comment: The performance difference, if any, is likely to be VERY small. It shouldn't matter and I would classify it as micro-optimization.

Comment: Then both of you haven't read the question. It said: "`However, I’ve heard developers criticize the array_push() function, so I wonder if there is a better way to go about this.`" I wouldn't go recommend people to change their code out of the blue, but if it is asked directly, I will, and I've got PHP.net to back me up. If you've done some measurements, you should have notices that function calls are terribly slow in PHP. For instance, I've seen an application that uses getter methods become 30% faster when they were changed to direct property access. That doesn't seem micro.

Comment: And of course, there is a difference between writing more, more verbose or less readable code for micro optimization, or using a function or construct that is just as easy to read and as easy to write, and still is faster. That not evil, that's just a quickwin.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I've removed my downvote because you added this "*Personally I always use the [] notation, mainly because I think it's cleaner, but it's also faster.*". That's the only reason you should change it. **Very slight performance differences are not a valid reason to stop using functions.** If your app times out because of a silly function call, you have much bigger things to worry about.

Comment: @AmalMurali Of course, and I don't stop using functions. I even didn't  in that application that became so much faster without them. But when you have a big webshop (and I work for one), and you notice 7% increase in conversion when your website loads 20% faster, then performance *is* an issue. It can earn you millions a year. Not because of time-outs, that's hardly ever an issue, but just because a faster website is more appealing to customers. Nevertheless, we didn't eliminate all those getters, but we always keep an open eye for quick wins in performance. PS: I didn't make those numbers up.

Comment: @GolezTrol: If something can be optimized and you can, by all means do it. I'm just saying it doesn't make sense to just stop `array_push` because it's slow (it's really not). The performance difference isn't even noticeable unless you run it on a loop with millions of iterations. Sure, it'd matter if you're a Facebook-sized website or close, but in all other cases it's just pointless.

Comment: This answers describes the fundamental difference between two functionally equivalent constructs. This is not opinion-based, since the doc itself states it might be the better option in this case. But it's also true that the mentioned overhead is really thin. A quick benchmark shows a difference of about half a microsecond per run, this is not even hardly noticeable on most of the code you'll write.